# Can i create a linked list in this way?

Tags: c++

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node *link;
} n1, n2;
n1.data = 1;
n1.link = &n2;  //in the link pointer of n1 store the address of n2
n2.data = 2;
```

Is the above code correct?
What command should I write to print the data of the node whose address is stored  in the link of n1.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. To print the data: `cout << n1.link->data;`.

Comment: It correct, but it's also fairly useless, because the point of a linked list is that you can extend it indefinitely. With a linked list declared that way your list is determined by the number of node variables you declare. You might as well use an array.

Comment: I would say incorrect as `n2.link` is not initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the above code correct?

It will compile, and run, but it would make sense to set `n2.link = NULL;` so that your other code can find where the end of the list is.

> What command should I write to print the data of the node whose address is stored in the link of n1.

```
printf("%d\n", n1.link->data);
```

Comment: It's C++. it's better than to use `nullptr` and `cout`.